# Consumer not consuming message Service Bus Queue

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying Service bus queue for my knowledge recently in ASP.NET Core 5.0 where I have created Producer webapi and a consumer web API and using masstransite. But due to some  reason I am not able to consume the message.

Message Producer Code controller:

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("sender")]
        public async Task SendUsingAzureServiceBusQeue()
        {
            try
            {
                var sendEndpoint =
                await _serviceEndPointProvider.GetSendEndpoint(
                    new Uri("myservicebusurl/test"));
                await sendEndpoint.Send<Test>(new Test { message = "Hi This message from sender" });
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Producer Startup Class Settings:

```cs
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host("Endpoint=myservicebusconnectionstring");
                });
            });

            services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo { Title = "AKS Example", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
```

Consumer Code Startup class:

```cs
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
           
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    
                    x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
                    {
                        cfg.Host("Endpoint=myservicebusconnectionstring");
                        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("test", endpoint =>
                        {
                            endpoint.ConfigureConsumer<MessageConsumer>(context);
                        });
                    });
                    x.AddConsumer<MessageConsumer>();
                });
            services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);
            services.AddControllers();
        }
```

Consumer Code Consumer Class:

```cs
     public class MessageConsumer : IConsumer<Test>
    {
        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Test> context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Message processed: Message:{context.Message.message}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

I am able to see message are being pushed but not received on consumer side.
Also I noticed there is a Topic being created though I am using queue only name "test" for publish and subscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that both projects have the same message type, including namespace [as pointed out in the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/messages.html).

Comment: Its there after x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg). I tested before and after both, but did't work

Comment: Messages in the same namespace? Check the logs?

Comment: Earlier My models were in two different namespace. I modified it created a common models project which is being shared between Producer and Consumer and started working. Thanks for your quick input. Please update the answer, I will accept it